# How to refresh page after java method finishes execution

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, velocity

I have a Java EE application, that uses Velocity to display the HTML pages. My problem is with redirecting the page or Refreshing the page after my java method ConfigurationF3Controller() finishes execution, what parameters should I pass to my veloCity object so that it will reload the same page after my method finishs ?

The code below is the velocity template snippet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="color.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">

<div id="conteneur" class="import-woalis">
    <div class="info-title">
        <span class="portefeuille"><u> Fichier de configuration F3</u></span>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="descriptif-contrat">
            <table cellspacing="10" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <span class="libelle" style="width: 130px">Configuartion File<br />file type F3</span>
                        <form action="fichier-configuration-f3.html?action=importerFichierConfiguration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="importerFichierConfForm">
                            <input type="file" name="file" size="50" id="check" />
                        </form>     
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="libelle" style="color: red;"><u>Attention :</u><br>file mist be of UNIX type</span>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <div class="button-box"><input type="button" class="button button-import" onclick="document.importerFichierConfForm.submit();"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <span class="libelle">actual file contents : </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <textarea  cols="90%" rows="25" readonly="true" style="resize: none" >$fileControllerF3</textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second code snippet is to load the start page and fill it with the contents of a file on a unix server.

```
public class ConfigurationF3Controller extends MainController {

    public ModelAndView begin(final HttpServletRequest pRequest, final HttpServletResponse pResponse) throws Exception {
        final Context vContext = getContext(pRequest, pResponse);

        if (null == vContext) {
            return null;
        }

        final VelocityContext vVelocityContext = new VelocityContext();

        final String vNomdePage = "administration/fichier-configuration-f3.vm";

        // file fileF3 will contain the path and the file name on the server  Constantes.PARAM_IMPORT_FICHIER_F3
        final String vRepertoireF3 = ParamDelegator.getParameter(Constantes.PARAM_IMPORT_FICHIER_F3);
        final File fileF3 = new File(vRepertoireF3 + Constantes.NAME_FILE_CONFIG_F3);

        // call for a method which uses Buffered reader to read the file on the server        
        String fileControllerF3 = getFileConfigurationF3(fileF3);

        // call for velocity to put the contents of the read file in the html field called fileControllerF3(see first part of the code)
        vVelocityContext.put("fileControllerF3", fileControllerF3);

        affichePage(vNomdePage, vContext, pRequest, pResponse, vVelocityContext, Constantes.EC_ADM_FICHIER_CONFIG_F3);

        return null;
    }

    //Another Method to display nothing on the page!
    public ModelAndView affichePagePrincp(final HttpServletRequest pReq, final HttpServletResponse pResponse)
            throws Exception {

        final Context vContext = getContext(pReq, pResponse);

        if (null == vContext) {
            return null;
        }

        final VelocityContext vVelocityContext = new VelocityContext();
        final String vNomdePage = "administration/fichier-configuration-f3.vm";
        final String stringBlank = "";

        vVelocityContext.put("fileControllerF3", stringBlank);

        affichePage(vNomdePage, vContext, pReq, pResponse, vVelocityContext, Constantes.EC_ADM_FICHIER_CONFIG_F3);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking 2 unrelated questions here. Please edit your question so that it's just one of these questions

Comment: ok changed it. now any answers ?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need to refresh the page after the java method finishes.**

When you perform an http GET request on a servlet you would generally expect the http response to contain the page content

So what you need to do is render the velocity template and attach it to the response

Comment: @Baturay If this isn't clear then please include the code for `affichePage()` as it looks like this is where the magic should happen